# Inner Join multiple relations vs Join 2 relations at a time. Which way is performant?

Tags: join, apache-pig, inner-join

I have 4 relations A, B, C and D each containing a field id (with other fields). I want to INNER join these relations on id, so that final relation should have only the ids which are part of all A, B, C and D relations. I can do this in multiple ways:

```
1. X = JOIN A BY id, B BY id, C BY id, D BY id;

2. X = JOIN A BY id, B BY id;
   Y = JOIN C BY id, D BY id;
   Z = JOIN X BY A::id, Y BY C::id

3. X = JOIN A BY id, B BY id;
   Y = JOIN X BY B::id, C BY id;
   Z = JOIN Y BY C::id, D BY id;
```

How do I decide which of the above way is most performance. What all things do I need to consider (e.g. size of A..D, the number of columns needed from each A..D in the final relation etc) before choosing one of the above ways?